# Getting WSDL from VS2010 WCF Service application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, wsdl

I Just created a sample WCF Service application  in Visual Studio 2010. It has the following configuration and service code.  I need to see the corresponding WSDL generated. What I need to do to see the corresponding WSDL?

[image]

CODE

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }
}
```

**REFERENCES**

1. [How to generate a wsdl file of a wcf service library project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128672/how-to-generate-a-wsdl-file-of-a-wcf-service-library-project?rq=1)
2. [Is there any way I can create a WSDL file from WCF Service Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178350/is-there-any-way-i-can-create-a-wsdl-file-from-wcf-service-application?rq=1)
3. [WSDL automatically generated by WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222697/wsdl-automatically-generated-by-wcf?rq=1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can right click on svc file and select view in browser option. Then, add ?WSDL to the end of URL. It would show the WSDL file.

You can also make use of SVCUtil for this.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add `?wsdl` to the end of your service url.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to export the WSDL to a file you can use SVCUtil to accomplish this.

```
svcutil /t:metadata http://servername/path/WCFSeviceApplication.svc?singleWsdl
```